# How to avoid pagebreak in two-column article

Tags: floats, ieeetran

I'm having some problems writing an 2-columns article with IEEEtrans document class. After compiling my file, I keep finding a page break without it being completed (check figure). It starts a new page with a new session and brings a float equation at its beginning (check figure) 
[image]

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\captionsetup[table]{format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=period}%
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
```

I tried a lot of things: the command \nopagebreak[], the float environment to avoid the float to go to the next page, the minipage environment... but I'm not succeding. Could you guys help me? I need to use all blank spaces cause the articles max number of pages is 5.

Comment: Looks like you have a figure that's too wide for one column! Scale it to fit (comfortably) in one column, and I think you also need to explicitly request a one-column float.

Comment: @alexis I have tried making a figure too large using IEEEtran class. The figure simply overlaps the text in the next column. So I doubt this is the problem.

Comment: Is there a table 2 on page 3?

Comment: @Pierre No,  there's a table 2 on page 4

Comment: Ok, what's the first thing on page 4? This may be forcing the break. Start removing things and see if/when the break goes away.

Comment: Incidentally, your header is not a "Minimal Working Example": It is not enough for me to reproduce the problem (hence: not "working example"), and we don't know which of the packages are relevant to the problem (hence: not "minimal"). If you could provide a real one, someone will fix you up in no time.

Comment: @alexis Ok, this is the part where the problem occurs [Problem](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/4043/dltv.png); I can't finish the 3rd page completely, there's page break... I can't remove those equations, cause I need them.

Comment: Paste a document we can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The quickest solution is probably not to put your equations in floats. There any number of ways to get captions without using a float, e.g., package `capt-of.sty`.

Comment: @alexis [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/an55v4ryr2f77mz/LaTeX1.tex) is the link to my latex file